# Hibernate - How to make hibernate and in-memory grid solution work simultaneously with?

Tags: hibernate, caching, in-memory

In my server I need to server high method calls rate (300 method calls per second).
In order to stand this requirement I know that I need a cache/in-memory solution.

**The conflict is how to do that when I'm using hibernate:**

1. If I will use Hibernate 2nd level cache **doesn't saves the real entity** but the identifier, thus, it doesn't fit.
2. If I will use an in-memory solution as Infinispan or Couchbase I will need to **develop a  layer that doe's** duplicated works (save/delete/update to DB and memory).

Is there any way that I can save/update/delete a JPA Entity to hibernate and to in-memory grid without to develop a layer that doe's that?

I also tried to find the Hibernate API docs but it looks deprecated (if someone can redirect me I'll be happy).

Thanks!
Tomer

Answer (score 0):

One option for an in-memory cache provider is [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com).

I don't use their back-end persistence features, but they provide a pluggable [GridCacheStore](http://www.gridgain.com/javadoc40DG/index.html?org/gridgain/grid/cache/GridCache.html) interface, so that when you call gridGainCache.put(...) it will, either synch (by default) or async (using write-behind), write the new entry in to the persistence layer.

Documentation is [here](http://www.gridgain.com/book/book.html#_key_concepts), note that they have an example that uses Hibernate to handle the content.

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that the only thing that you want is to replace the cache of Hibernate? and not the persistance layer?

So if you want is to have a "faster" 2nd level cache into Hibernate, have you tested with Infinispan ( https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Using+Infinispan+as+JPA-Hibernate+Second+Level+Cache+Provider ) that is a cache solution. This is probably the best option today. Couchbase is more than a cache (it has a memcached based cache but also allow you to persist the data onto the disk as a NoSQL Engine).

Just in case you may have seen Hibernate OGM ( http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/ogm.html ) that allows you to store data into the NoSQL instance, and not into a RDBMS instance. I am currently working on a Couchbase provider for OGM. ( https://github.com/tgrall/hibernate-ogm/tree/couchbase-support )